# JUnit mock of Environment with Mockito not working, evaluating to null still

Tags: java, junit, mockito, autowired

I have a class `MyClass` which has `@Autowired private Environment env;` in it.  It also has `public MyFunctionA()`, which calls `private MyFunctionB()`, and in `MyFunctionB()`, it calls `env.getProperty(propName)` which will return a string value from a properties file to `MyFunctionA()` as a factor in its computation.  But currently, when debugging JUnit test, I can't mock env without getting `null`.

The unit test class `MyServiceTest` for `MyClass` starts out as follows:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock 
    final Environment env = Mockito.mock(Environment.class);

    MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       Mockito.when(this.env.getProperty("myProperty")).thenReturn("1234,2345");

        myService = new MyServiceImpl();
```

Later on, in the unit test function, it calls `MyFunctionA()` but debugging shows that `MyFunctionB()` encounters NPE when making the `env.getProperty` call. What could be wrong? The test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void myUnitTest() throws IOException {
    boolean boolFlag = myService.MyFunctionA();
    assertTrue(boolFLag);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. You override the mock object created by the `@Mock` annotation by explicitly assigning a new (mocked) value to `env`.
2. You're missing the `@InjectMocks` annotation to inject the mocked `env` to your `myService` member:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock 
    Environment env; // issue #1

    @InjectMocks // issue #2
    MyServiceImpl myService = new MyServiceImpl()

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       Mockito.when(this.env.getProperty("myProperty")).thenReturn("1234,2345");
    }

    // Tests ...
```

Comment: ```Mockito.doReturn("1234,2345").when(this.env.getProperty("myProperty"));```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mureinik said, there were issuing with your object creation. However, if you rely on annotations from Mockito, you need to initialize objects using runner `MockitoJUnitRunner` or calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

**Final configuration:**

```
public class MyServiceTest {

@Mock 
Environment env;

@InjectMocks
MyServiceImpl myService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   Mockito.when(this.env.getProperty("myProperty")).thenReturn("1234,2345");
}

// Tests ...
```

Comment: this.env.getProperty("myProperty") is not finding get method... Please help!